# Funcion que reciba como parametro un objeto y una propiedad y retorne el valor de esa propiedad en el objeto en Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

necesito hacer una función en Javascript que sea genérica, es decir, que reciba 2 parametros (objeto y propiedad) y que busque esa propiedad en el objeto y retorne el valor de esa propiedad en el objeto.

```
function parserValue(obj, prop){
   return obj[prop];
}

let datos= {id: 1, name: 'Primero'};

console.log(parserValue(datos, name))
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar lo que has intentado. Si no tienes idea de qué hacer, lee [esta página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty), seguramente te va a ser muy útil.

Comment: agrega tu codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno realmente no te funciona porque la segunda propiedad la estás enviando como si fuese una variable y no un string. Para acceder a la propiedad del objeto debes pasarle una string.

```
function parserValue(obj, prop){
   return obj[prop];
}

let datos= {id: 1, name: 'Primero'};

console.log(parserValue(datos, "name"))
// Esto te va retornar: "Primero"
```